# Why does the SVG image not become resized using Apache Batik and the Mac Renderer?

Tags: java, apache, svg, resize, batik

Currently I am working with an application that scales and displays SVG background images using a custom viewer JComponent which extends JSVGCanvas. Once the View class is added to a JViewPort, it should load the SVG image, resize it to fit the JViewPort’s size, and then display the image.

The result should look like follows:

[image: Properly scaled SVG image]

However on my MacBook (OS X 10.8.5) using Java 1.7.0_51 it comes out like follows:

[image: SVG image has not been scaled]

On my Mac, the moment I resize the application window (and thus fire the componentResized method), the SVG image resizes properly as shown in the first picture.

I have tried:

- Adding a call to adjustBackgroundComponentScale() after calling loadBackgroundImage().
- Using three different SVG images and all of them behaved as the second picture shows – meaning the images themselves are not the problem.
- Adding a breakpoint to the paintComponent method. The size of the backgroundComponent was 1342x552, which is the size of the viewport. However, the gvtRoot > bounds showed 399 x 397 (approximately the original size of the image – meaning the image had not scaled).

I am puzzled by where this problem is occurring. If the size of the background component has been correctly set to 1342x552, how come the image does not resize until the window is resized?

Here is the related portion of the View class:

```
public class View extends JPanel {

    private final class BackgroundImageLoader implements AncestorListener {
        private ComponentListener listener;

        BackgroundImageLoader(final ComponentListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
            loadBackgroundImage();
            getParent().addComponentListener(listener);
        }

        public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {
            getParent().removeComponentListener(listener);
        }

        public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {
        }
    }

    private JComponent backgroundComponent;
    private boolean fitToViewport;

    public MapView() {
        // Other code...
        final String fitToViewportAsString = MapStyle
                .getController(modeController).getPropertySetDefault(model,
            MapStyle.FIT_TO_VIEWPORT);
        fitToViewport = Boolean.parseBoolean(fitToViewportAsString);
        final ComponentAdapter backgroundImageResizer = 
                new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (fitToViewport) {
                    adjustBackgroundComponentScale();
                }
            }
        };
        addAncestorListener(new BackgroundImageLoader(backgroundImageResizer));
    }

    public void mapChanged(final MapChangeEvent event) {
        final Object property = event.getProperty();
        if (property.equals(MapStyle.RESOURCES_BACKGROUND_IMAGE)) {
            loadBackgroundImage();
            adjustViewportScrollMode();
        }
        if (property.equals(MapStyle.FIT_TO_VIEWPORT)) {
            final String fitToViewportAsString = MapStyle
                    .getController(modeController).getPropertySetDefault(model,
                MapStyle.FIT_TO_VIEWPORT);
            fitToViewport = Boolean.parseBoolean(fitToViewportAsString);
            adjustViewportScrollMode();
            adjustBackgroundComponentScale();
        }
    }

    private void loadBackgroundImage() {
        final MapStyle mapStyle = getModeController().getExtension(MapStyle.class);
        final String uriString = mapStyle
                .getProperty(model, MapStyle.RESOURCES_BACKGROUND_IMAGE);
        backgroundComponent = null;
        if (uriString != null) {
            URI uri = assignAbsoluteURI(uriString);
            final ViewerController vc = getModeController()
                    .getExtension(ViewerController.class);
            final IViewerFactory factory = vc.getCombiFactory();
            if (uri != null) {
                assignViewerToBackgroundComponent(factory, uri);
            }
        }
        adjustViewportScrollMode();
    }

    private URI assignAbsoluteURI(final String uriString) {
        final UrlManager urlManager = getModeController()
                .getExtension(UrlManager.class);
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = urlManager.getAbsoluteUri(model, new URI(uriString));
        }
        catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
            LogUtils.severe(e);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            LogUtils.severe(e);
        }
        return uri;
    }

    private void assignViewerToBackgroundComponent(final IViewerFactory factory, 
                                                   final URI uri) {
        try {
            final JViewport vp = (JViewport) getParent();
            if (vp != null) {
                final Dimension viewPortSize = vp.getVisibleRect().getSize();
                backgroundComponent = (JComponent) factory
                        .createViewer(uri, viewPortSize);
            }
            ((ScalableComponent) backgroundComponent).setCenter(true);
            ((ScalableComponent) backgroundComponent)
            .setImageLoadingListener(new ImageLoadingListener() {
                public void imageLoaded() {
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (final MalformedURLException e1) {
            LogUtils.severe(e1);
        }
        catch (final IOException e1) {
            LogUtils.severe(e1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (backgroundComponent != null) {
            paintBackgroundComponent(g);
        }
    }

    private void paintBackgroundComponent(final Graphics g) {
        Graphics backgroundGraphics = g.create();
        try {
            setBackgroundComponentLocation(backgroundGraphics);
            backgroundComponent.paint(backgroundGraphics);
        }
        finally {
            backgroundGraphics.dispose();
        }
    }

    private void setBackgroundComponentLocation(Graphics g) {
        final JViewport vp = (JViewport) getParent();
        final Point viewPosition = vp.getViewPosition();
        g.translate(viewPosition.x, viewPosition.y);
    }

    private void adjustBackgroundComponentScale() {
        if (backgroundComponent != null) {
            final JViewport vp = (JViewport) getParent();
            final Dimension viewPortSize = vp.getVisibleRect().getSize();
            ((ScalableComponent) backgroundComponent)
            .setFinalViewerSize(viewPortSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the related portion of the custom viewer component:

```
public class SvgViewerFactory implements IViewerFactory {
    private ViewerComponent canvas;

    private final class ViewerComponent extends 
                        JSVGCanvas implements ScalableComponent {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Dimension originalSize = null;

        public void setFinalViewerSize(final Dimension sizeWithScaleCorrection) {
            setRenderingTransform(initialTransform);
            setPreferredSize(sizeWithScaleCorrection);
            setMySize(sizeWithScaleCorrection);
            setSize(sizeWithScaleCorrection);
        }

        public ViewerComponent(final URI uri) {
            this(uri, null);
        }

        public ViewerComponent(final URI uri, final Dimension size) {
            super(null, false, false);
            setDocumentState(ALWAYS_STATIC);
            setSize(1, 1);
            addGVTTreeRendererListener(new GVTTreeRendererAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void gvtRenderingStarted(final GVTTreeRendererEvent e) {
                    super.gvtRenderingStarted(e);
                    final SVGDocument document = getSVGDocument();
                    final SVGSVGElement rootElement = document.getRootElement();
                    final SVGLength width = rootElement.getWidth().getBaseVal();
                    final SVGLength height = rootElement.getHeight()
                            .getBaseVal();
                    float defaultWidth = (float) Math.ceil(width.getValue());
                    float defaultHeigth = (float) Math.ceil(height.getValue());
                    if (defaultWidth == 1f && defaultHeigth == 1f) {
                        defaultWidth = ResourceController
                                .getResourceController().getIntProperty(
                            "default_external_component_width", 200);
                        defaultHeigth = ResourceController
                                .getResourceController().getIntProperty(
                            "default_external_component_height", 200);
                    }
                    originalSize = new Dimension
                            ((int) defaultWidth, (int) defaultHeigth);
                    if ("".equals(rootElement.getAttributeNS(
                        null, SVGConstants.SVG_VIEW_BOX_ATTRIBUTE))) {
                        rootElement.setAttributeNS(null, 
                            SVGConstants.SVG_VIEW_BOX_ATTRIBUTE, 
                            "0 0 " + defaultWidth
                                + " " + defaultHeigth);
                    }
                    if (size == null) {
                        setSize(originalSize);
                    }
                    else {
                        setSize(size);
                    }
                    removeGVTTreeRendererListener(this);
                }
            });
            setURI(uri.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (originalSize == null) {
                return new Dimension(1, 1);
            }
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }

        public void setImageLoadingListener(final ImageLoadingListener listener) 
        {
            addGVTTreeRendererListener(new GVTTreeRendererAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void gvtRenderingCompleted(GVTTreeRendererEvent e) {
                    listener.imageLoaded();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ScalableComponent createViewer(final URI uri, 
                                          final Dimension preferredSize) {
        canvas = new ViewerComponent(uri, preferredSize);
        canvas.addGVTTreeRendererListener(new GVTTreeRendererAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void gvtRenderingCompleted(final GVTTreeRendererEvent e) {
                canvas.setFinalViewerSize(preferredSize);
                canvas.revalidate();
                canvas.removeGVTTreeRendererListener(this);
            }
        });
        return canvas;
    }

    public ScalableComponent getComponent() {
        return canvas;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your code works. You just need to figure out what event gets fired or what method gets called after the view loads, and call/attach your adjustBackgroundComponentScale() to that.

Comment: Unfortunately calling adjustBackgroundComponentScale after loadBackgroundImage in ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) method does not affect the result.